# step by step indexing into apache solr

Tags: apache, solr

I have started to work using apache nutch for crawling and I have been following the steps shown in apache wiki nutch tutorial. I was able to set up the solr server at port 8983 as shown in the instructions. I now try to do indexing using the said tool but i am getting the following errors:

```
Indexer: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/update. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>

at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.executeMethod(HttpSolrServer.java:512)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:210)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:206)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:124)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.commit(SolrServer.java:168)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.commit(SolrServer.java:146)
at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.commit(SolrIndexWriter.java:164)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.commit(IndexWriters.java:125)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:149)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:222)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:231)
```

I am using solr for the first time so any help in this in will be great as I did not find other solutions which work for me.

Comment: what is the query you are running?

Comment: I am trying to integrate nutch with solr and send the crawl data from nutch to solr I was doing the exercise using the instructions from the nutch tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is **/solr/update**. The latest version of Solr no longer supports default collection (the missing name between **/solr** and **/update**).

So, if you are using latest (5.x) Solr, you need that URL to reflect the collection name that you have created. So check Nutch tutorial or documentation on how to provide an explicit collection name in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same error when running Apache Nutch 1.11 and Apache Solr 5.3.1. The problem was resolved by including the core name ( **test_core** in the example below) in the solr.server.url

```
bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/test_core urls/ TestCrawl/  2
```